# Pipe process to target stdin in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

How can I pipe the `stdout` of a command executed on the host (admin) machine to the `stdin` of a process on the target (remote) machine, using a playbook?

To illustrate, imagine I wanted to do the following via Ansible instead of `ssh` (`echo` and `dd` are arbitrary placeholders for the actual scripts)

```
echo hello world | ssh remote 'dd of=message.txt'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the following task composition:

```
    - command: '<remote command>'
      args:
        stdin: "{{ lookup('pipe','<local command>') }}"
```

For example:

```
    - command: 'dd of=message.txt'
      args:
        stdin: "{{ lookup('pipe','echo hello world') }}"
```

References:

- [`command` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html)
- [`pipe` lookup documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/pipe.html)